# Jquery load and refresh content

Tags: jquery, load

I use jquery for load content , in this case i have one pic in folder , the pic call pic.jpg , the name never change, this pic have the same name but change , in one case in one hour this pic can be different to other pic with the same name and in other hour

The problem it´s always show the same pic i use this for refresh and show content :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var auto_refresh = setInterval(

function ()
{   

var randnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*999999999999);
jQuery("#login_data_top_pic_profile").load("index_users.php?load_pic_profile=ok&rand_n="+randnumber);   

},3000);


});
</script>
```

I use rand number for see if it´s possible this fix the problem but continue

In the file call from jquery load i have the image :

```
<img src="user_folder/pic.jpg">
```

Have the same name but no change and show the new pic when user load for example other

I think cache problem but i can´t fix finally

Regards and Thank´s

Comment: Note that the jQuery `.load()` method is the same as: `$.ajax()` and `.get()` and `.post()`. $.ajax is the "full" version of the command, while .load, .post and .get are shortcut versions of $.ajax() that make assumptions about what you want to do. user2310289 has a good answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the $.ajax call, then you can set the cache option to false.

See

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.

E.g

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index_users.php?load_pic_profile=ok",
  cache: false
})
.done(function( pic) {
$( "#login_data_top_pic_profile" ).append( pic);
});
```

Comment: I don´t know how use with this script that , can you put example , please , thank´s , regards